# in python , How to load just one time a ML model in a rest service like django or flask?

Tags: python, django, machine-learning, scikit-learn, django-rest-framework

I have a ML model saved in a pkl (pickel file),  I have no problem loading this model and using it for prediction, even I have a rest service that expose it, the only problem is that I load the model in every request, something like this:

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/09/machine-learning-models-as-apis-using-flask/

I really want that my model just load one time like a global variable and every request useing this variable without the necessity of  load the model every request

is it possible?

Answer (score 7):

You can assign the model variable in `settings.py`. Whenever the server will start/restart django will store the model variable globally. It can be accessed like

```
from django.conf import settings 
print settings.my_ml_model_variable
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on the comment of Kaushal, I solved my problem using django rest framework as the following:

first I saved my model as :

```
> joblib.dump(<your scikit model here> , <"yourfilename.pkl">, compress
> = 1)
```

Once I had my model saved with the pkl extension I needed to create a variable in the settings.py file(this file is created automatically by django)

```
YOURMODEL = joblib.load(<"yourfilename.pkl">)
```

The django process call this file when you start your server, so it is called just one time

Now we just need to call our model in whatever place we want, usually in a views.py file since we are using django and/or django-rest-framework

```
myModel = getattr(settings, 'YOURMODEL', 'the_default_value')

res = myModel.predict_proba(s).tolist()
```

A simple example of the rest service:

```
from django.conf import settings 

class myClass(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    '''Httpverb post method'''
    def post(self, request,format=None):

        myModel = getattr(settings, '../mymodel.pkl', 'the_default_value')
        data = preparePostData(request.data)
        res = myModel.predict_proba(data).tolist()
        message = prepareMessage(res)
        return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Here preparePostData and prepareMessage are just function that I developed for prepare the object to my model and  my response

Regards

Comment: I am happy that my answer helped. You can upvote and accept the answer also so that it will be marked as useful answer and it will be helpful for people facing similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in Django by creating yourfile.py config.

Just you should redfine the django AppConfig there, and instanciate your models .

It will load all your models when django is starting for just once .

After that you can use it in views simpely by importing your class models from yourfile.py .

**To do that you should define Yourfile.py**

It should look like that :

```
  from django.apps import AppConfig

  class YourModelsConfig(AppConfig):

        #write what you need
```

And in your views you can do:

```
 from yourfile import YourModelsConfig


 YourModelsConfig.your_method_or_your_variable
```

I think you can get more details here .

https://medium.com/saarthi-ai/deploying-a-machine-learning-model-using-django-part-1-6c7de05c8d7v