# Sharing resources in different instances in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on vosk (Speech to text conversion) library, Implementing in python project.

```
Vosk Link : https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api
```

I have this line of code

```
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer, SetLogLevel
model = Model("model")
```

`model=Model("model")` this line loads a large file into a memory, I want to load this model only once and every other instance can share it.

> init.py

```
class Model(object):

    def __init__(self, model_path):
        self._handle = _c.vosk_model_new(model_path.encode('utf-8'))

        if self._handle == _ffi.NULL:
            raise Exception("Failed to create a model")

    def __del__(self):
        _c.vosk_model_free(self._handle)

    def vosk_model_find_word(self, word):
        return _c.vosk_model_find_word(self._handle, word.encode('utf-8'))
..
..
```

Any solution in Python. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to share it between different instances of the Python interpreter? Not possible, unless you map that model in memory and provide a shared access to it. I don't know if this is correct, just an idea.

Comment: @demberto: As this model file is too large if different users load it then it will create time is there any way to load it only once for all users?

Comment: What are "users"? Are they just different instances of the Python interpreter? Or are they different users on a network? Or on a local machine? What exactly?

Comment: @demberto: Yes for every users different instances will be created and at the same time different instances will load model which will consume extra memory and time

Comment: If you are on a forking system like linux, subprocesses share a copy-on-write view of the parent memory space. A master program could create the model and fork the users.

Comment: @tdelaney: Can you please give some examples link? is this also possible with static methods?

Comment: There is a difference between the file and the objects it expands into in memory. Its generally difficult to share python objects because they live in a process specific memory pool. You can create shared memory, but the python objects won't live there.

Comment: What does "load a large file into memory" mean? If its just reading the raw bytes, you could use [mmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html#module-mmap) and share the physical memory. But if you've processed that model into python objects, that's a different problem entirely. And if the processed file is a numpy array, more complications still.

Comment: @tdelaney: It is being processed in python objects `model = Model("model")` this is loading entire model in memory

Answer (score 0):

If "loading the file" means "creating a bunch of python objects", then you've got a problem. Python objects are allocated in a series of memory pools that are local to the process. Python doesn't allow you to create its objects in a shared memory space because its too complicated to try to sort out the memory allocation and linkage issues.

Except processes in forking operating systems like Linux share a copy-on-write view of its parent's memory. That includes all python objects in existence when `fork` is called. Any changes a subprocess makes create a copy of the memory private to that subprocess. Neither the parent nor any siblings see the changes.

To pull this off, you need a master that knows how to execute the programs you want. This can get complicated, depending on how dynamic you want it to be. But, a simple case is:

```
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer, SetLogLevel
import multiprocessing as mp

def do_thing_1(model):
    pass
    
def do_thing_2(model):
    pass
    
def do_thing_3(model)
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    assert mp.get_start_methd() == "fork", "Requires 'forking' operating system"
    model = Model("model")
    processes = []
    processes.append(mp.Process(target=do_thing_1, args=(model,)))
    processes.append(mp.Process(target=do_thing_2, args=(model,)))
    processes.append(mp.Process(target=do_thing_3, args=(model,)))
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i checked this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51430094/in-python-how-to-load-just-one-time-a-ml-model-in-a-rest-service-like-django-o I want solution something like this only, because i'm also loading ML model file can this be achieved in python without django